# Set the Default Print Page size for Microsoft Word

Tags: vb.net, printing, ms-word

Im working with vb.net and microsoft word using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and everything is fine. My only problem is I cant find a way to change the default page size **printing** setting from "letter" to "A4". 
This code was doing the job for Crystal reports but isnt doing it for Word

`Dim pp As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
        For i = 0 To pp.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1
            If pp.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Item(i).Kind = System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A4 Then
                pp.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pp.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Item(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next`

Comment: One observation with a question like this is "why don't you use Word to do the printing?".  Which entirely explains the problem, Word doesn't know anything about PrintDocument.

Comment: +1 I cant find a way, but can you remove the code in the question its confusing that your trying to set Word Default Page size with .Net System.Drawing.Printing methods. .Net code works with Word using VSTO.

Comment: @HansPassant another observation with an observation like this is "the problem is not having to change the printing page size everytime I want to print a page even through word"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/45152591-1f3e-4d1e-b767-ef030be9d9f2

Since page size can vary from section to section, the best thing is to set the PageSetup properties of the Document.Section object. For example, you can loop through all the sections of the document:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    Word.Document doc = app.ActiveDocument;
    foreach (Section section in doc.Sections)
    {
        section.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4;
    }
}
```

Adding locic to set paper size when a document is created or opened is up to you, I'm guessing you'll need to determine if the document being opened has purposely been saved in a non-A4 size.

**EDIT: This does work**, I dont know what you mean with the comment `ThisAddIn isnt a member or Globals and ActiveDocument isnt a member of Application in VB.NET` - you cant skip these top two lines, here is the VB.Net version:

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim app As Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document = app.ActiveDocument
    For Each section As Section In doc.Sections
        section.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4
    Next
End Sub
```

All you need to do is > Visual Studio > Create a New Prorject > Office > Word 2010 (or 2007) Add-In and paste in the above code. Here is a screenshot showing it works with A4 and Letter:

[image]

The only issue you may face is when the Printer doesn't have the size paper you get this error: `Requested PaperSize is not available on the currently selected printer.`

Comment: this looks like it should work, is there any references I need? Cause ThisAddIn isnt a member or Globals and ActiveDocument isnt a member of Application in VB.NET

Comment: I didnt use the first two lines of code, I just replaced doc.Sections with wordDoc.Sections (the instance I had created), and didnt work, the page size is changing but the printing size isnt changing.. Again if you try changing the page size manually the printing size changes to the same size!

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy Thompson the script worked, but the letter size you circled in the screenshot isnt the one I am trying to change. In the same screenshot, if you go up a little, click on printer properties -> Paper -> Paper Options -> Size 
That size isnt changing and thats the one Im trying to change

Comment: good lord! This has nothing to do with Microsoft Word, now I see what your original code was supposed to be doing. Open a new question, include the code I edited out of your question, dont mention anything about Word and show a screen shot.

Comment: yes maybe it has nothing to do with MS Word, but the original code was working with Crystal Reports. So im not sure there is a problem with the code, the problem is using it with Word.

Comment: Unfortunetly the downvotes just banned me from asking anymore questions. Even though my question was clear from the beginning and I never said it was a MS Word issue, I just said that the code was not changing  the printer settings size, and I didnt even place the VSTO tag. I replaced my original code and removed the tag

Comment: dude, I feel the pain. Simply ask a new question. Look I have to apologize as of late there's been a outburst of total noob questions. Your question is two fold and came off as a `chameleon question`. You wrote to @Steve: "The code is good, and its changing the size of the page, but the problem is when printing, the default page size is always set to "Letter" - and thats the question I answered. Look no harm, no foul, just post another '1 answer is only possible" question mate. With the screen shot and the code you did post in your initial question. Lets leave it, accept and I'll return fav.

Comment: When I told @Steve the default page size is always set to "Letter" I meant the printing size, I should have said the word "printing", but I assumed you all understood the question from the start which is very clear even from the title. And I cant ask anymore questions

Comment: This isnt the exact answer I am looking for, but considering the effort and the fact that it it the closest i shall go with it.. and you dont need that code to change the size where you pointed on the screenshot, just a simple 
>myWordDoc.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4  
will do the job

Answer (score 2):

You should change the PaperSize of the PageSetup interface on your Word Document instance.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
....

Dim myWordApp as Application = New Application();  
Dim myWordDoc As Document = myWordApp.Documents.Open("your_file_name_here")
myWordDoc.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4
```

Comment: i already tried this, but it wont change default printing page size. Even though if you manually change the page size of a word document, it changes the printing size too..

Comment: Actually I am getting an error: "Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))"

Comment: I fixed that problem. It seems it needs VS is faster than the loaded word document. Anyways  @JeremyThompson your code works and changed the size of the page, but when printing, the default page size doesnt change

Comment: @Haz I didn't post any code (but I'm glad it works), I asked you to post your code showing you've tried Steve's approach that doesn't work?

Comment: @JeremyThompson sorry i meant steve's code works, but it doesnt solve my problem cause it isnt changing the printing page size. My code isnt any different from the code above

Comment: @steve heres the code: Dim wordDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(docFile) Dim i As Integer = 1 For i = amountfrom To amountto Dim oBarcodeBookmark As Object = "Bookmark" & i Dim range As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = wordDoc.Bookmarks.Item(oBarcodeBookmark).Range Clipboard.SetDataObject(barcodeImage) range.Paste() Next wordDoc.PageSetup.PaperSize = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4

Comment: The code is good, and its changing the size of the page, but the problem is when printing, the default page size is always set to "Letter"

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting another answer to this question because the accepted answer doesn't refresh the document or handle page orientation. So just in case someone needs this I find this to be a much better solution...

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.ActiveDocument;

            foreach (Section section in doc.Sections)
            {
                if(section.PageSetup.Orientation == WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape)
                {
                    section.PageSetup.PageWidth = 841.88976378F;
                    section.PageSetup.PageHeight = 595.275590551F;

                }
                else
                {
                    section.PageSetup.PageWidth = 595.275590551F;
                    section.PageSetup.PageHeight = 841.88976378F;

                }

            }
```